# mustache.java pass json string

Tags: java, json, mustache, mustache.php

I am using mustache.java and wish to plug the json string instead of an object. I am not sure why no one faced this issue before.

```
// works since an 'Example' object is passed in
mustache.execute(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(objFile)), new Example()).flush();

// does not work since a json object is passed in directly
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\n" +
            "  \"header\": \"Colors\",\n" +
            "  \"items\": [\n" +
            "      {\"name\": \"red\", \"first\": true, \"url\": \"#Red\"},\n" +
            "      {\"name\": \"green\", \"link\": true, \"url\": \"#Green\"},\n" +
            "      {\"name\": \"blue\", \"link\": true, \"url\": \"#Blue\"}\n" +
            "  ],\n" +
            "  \"empty\": false\n" +
            "}");
mustache.execute(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(objFile)), jsonObject).flush();
```

Code here: https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java/blob/master/example/src/main/java/mustachejava/Example.java

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find a solution to this!

One can create a HashMap out of the json string and pass it to the mustache.execute method.

```
//create map using gson    
Map<String,Object> gsonMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
gsonMap = (Map<String,Object>) gson.fromJson(myJsonString, gsonMap.getClass());

//pass the hashmap instead of a class object
mustache.execute(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(objFile)), gsonMap).flush();
```